# How to import nacha text files through SSIS?

Tags: ssis

How to import nacha text files through SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

How do I import a text file into SSIS?
Here are the steps:

1. Sample SQL server database script.
2. Prepare source files for reading.
3. Configure project.
4. Configure ADO.NET connection to import text/CSV data into table.
5. Configure SSIS variable.
6. Configure script task in SSIS.